# getting error "Errors occurred during the build." on using ggts

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, logging

I am ggts to run my grails project. Whenever I save any edit i get a popup saying

'Building Workspace has encountered a problem'

on clicking on details I get

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'peelworkscustomer2.0'.
Could not initialize class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

I am unable to remove this error.

Comment: ggts is very buggy, i'm sure about that after using it for a while. Try to refresh dependencies, or use grails clean command.

Comment: suggest other open source ide for grails